# Building an IOS app just using a Webpage

Tags: ios

I'm new to IOS development and wanted to make an app for learning purposes. My idea is that I have a Single Webpage that has a live count of how many people are in the gyms on my University's Campus.

> How can I pull data from that webpage and show it on my app with a little bit of arithmetic such as :
>
> > Database how many people are usually in the gym at a particular time and then give predictions.
> >
> > let users chose a preferential gym and give them notifications based on their regular check in times
> >
> > if the rate of entry in the gym is high, then notify users to avoid going then. and vice-versa.

I don't want answer to all the above, but if you could give me a heading, that would be awesome!

EDIT 1:
The webpage looks like this : https://studentaffairs.psu.edu/CurrentFitnessAttendance/

Comment: you can use UIWebView :- https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwebview

Comment: Can I pull the actual data ? such as being able to monitor the script itself to pull the data ? Does that make sense ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too vague for a specific answer.

You need a back-end API into your web page. It could be as simples as a PHP or Python script that responds to http get requests and returns JSON data with the statistics you want. You'd then write your app to issue the appropriate query, parse the response, and display the results to your users.

Notifications would be more complicated. You'd probably need to set up remote notifications, which would require support on the server side and registering with Apple' remote notification service.

Comment: can i use the http request even if the website is not hosted by me ?